# How To Solve com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, ide, android-support-library

My codes are correct.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\mohammed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\mohammed\AndroidStudioProjects\Test4\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\mohammed\AndroidStudioProjects\Test4\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Answer (score 0):

enter to app.iml and check if your app and the library that you have installed have differents versions of the same jar, then delete the older version.

Answer (score 0):

It could be 2 reason for get this error.

1. May be you could twice import same jar in your libs Folder
2. Or may be you could twice define same attribute or line in your AndroidManifest.xml or any layout xml file.

You check them.

Good luck